# Incompatible Type when calling SoverOk function

Tags: excel, vba

I get incompatible type error when calling SolverOk function. Here's the code:

```
Dim alfaBetaAndGamaValuesRange As range
Set alfaBetaAndGamaValuesRange = prodSheet.range("$X$40:$X$42")
SolverReset
SolverOK SetCell:=prodSheet.range("X50"), MaxMinVal:=2, ByChange:=alfaBetaAndGamaValuesRange, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
```

The value of prodSheet.range when the function is called is 4.3653705... and alfaBetaAndGamaValuesRange contains only empty cells.

Thanks for the help.